# General DB practices for deleting a referenced item

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, database-design, database-normalization

Assume I have a theoretical database that lists a bunch of cars that can be rented out. The dealership can add\remove cars from their available inventory.

In psuedo code:

```
[Dealer]:
    [Id] PKEY
    [Name] NVARCHAR

[Car]:
    [Id] PKEY
    [DealerId] FKEY to [Dealer]
    [LicensePlate] NVARCHAR
```

A customer comes in and schedules a reservation...

```
[Customer]:
    [Id] PKEY

[Reservation]:
    [Id] PKEY
    [CarId] FKEY to [Car]
    [Date] -- for simplicity just say that a car can only be rented for a whole day
```

Now say that a dealership with a car that has been on their lot for years was sold. The dealer needs to remove the car from being available, but doesn't want all historical reservation data deleted. What's the best practice for this?

Some options seem to be:

**Option 1. Soft Delete -** Add a column on [Car] that signifies that is is no longer available

```
[Car]:
    [Id] PKEY
    [DealerId] FKEY to [Dealer]
    [LicensePlate] NVARCHAR
    [IsAvailable] BOOLEAN
```

My only issue with this is that if I had a unique constraint on [LicensePlate], then that would mean I couldn't add the car to another dealership unless I created some sort of `*->*` relationship (which might get chaotic considering a LicensePlate number can be retired & reused on different cars).

**Option 2. Convert past reservations to 1NF -** More than likely future reservations would need to be deleted anyway (can't have a reservation on a car not in the dealership). However, reservations in the past are no longer reservations. They're historical data at that point. I could create another table to handle past reservations that do not reference [Car], but instead are in 1NF.

```
[PastReservation]:
    [Id] PKEY
    [DealerId] FKEY to [Dealer] -- I guess it's not entirely 1NF...
    [LicensePlate] NVARCHAR
    [Date]
```

Are there other options? Any gotchas I should be aware of with either of these?

Comment: Use the vehicle identification number (VIN) instead of the license plate number as a unique identifier.  Creating a denormalized reservation history table seems like the better alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how VIN vs. LicensePlate as unique solves anything. A car that is sold to another dealership would have the same VIN and we'd have the same problem, wouldn't we? Or are you saying that [Car].[Id] should be the VIN?